# How to set up folder structure in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project and I can see lots of folders which are dimmed and have dotted outline. I can expand them and each usually contains several projects inside. These are not hidden folders. Also, when I try to open projects into windows explorer, it opens up in a differently named folder than what it appears in Visual Studio.

I want to know what is it and how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called [Solution Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/haytww03%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and they are not bound to the folder structure on the disk. If you open your solution file with a text editor, you can see how they reference the projects.